# NSOpenPanel not showing files after visiting folder for the first time

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsopenpanel

After days of debugging, I still can't figure out why NSOpenPanel (or NSSavePanel, for that matter) would show an empty file list after visiting a folder for the first time. It does so seemingly at random, i.e. sometimes files show up (possibly because they are cached), but, as it looks, not if a folder or volume is visited for the first time. If the user goes back and visits the same folder again, all files show up.

NSOpenPanel runs modally on the main thread, as required. There's another thread running. Lowering that other thread's priority did not help. Suspending it is not an option.

I suspect there's some **deferred event** that OS X sends to the panel (or app) after it finished retrieving the files (which potentially may take a while). For whatever reason, my NSOpenPanel seems to miss it.

What kind of event is that? How can I prevent it from getting lost?

EDIT: The NSOpenPanel is built and opened on the main thread by a delegate object. The panel is opened from the secondary thread with `[delegate performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector(runPanel) withObject: nil waitUntilDone: NO]`. So the secondary thread continues working immediately and polls the delegate until the panel finished, to fetch the results.

(It is this way, because the secondary thread runs a simulation that needs to continue while the user is providing input)

EDIT: The NSOpenPanel has an accessory view.

EDIT: Stack frame on main thread when panel is run.

```
-[SavePanelDelegate runPanel] + 185
-[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
__NSThreadPerformPerform + 318
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
__CFRunLoopRun + 1022
CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 394
CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 259
ReceiveNextEventCommon + 526
_BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 92
_DPSNextEvent + 1602
-[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 119
-[NSApplication run] + 727
NSApplicationMain + 1165
main + 99
```

Today I had difficulties reproducing the problem. It wasn't until after an hour or so and a reboot of the Mac, before it reoccurred again. Weird.

Comment: Put `NSLog(@"%@", [NSThread callStackSymbols]);` near the beginning of your `-runPanel` method and show the output. Also, is anything else logged to the console when this happens? Might as well show the code for your `-runPanel` method, too.

Comment: Nothing suscpicious on the stack frame or console. See it added to the post.

Comment: There is a temporary thread `TThumbnailExtractorThread` with `TConditionVariable::WaitWithTimeout()` involved after changing the file selection. It's probably collecting file icons to display. The thread disappears after a while. Since no errors are logged, it's difficult to assess if this is any relevant here.

Answer (score 2):

Are you running the open panel from a task submitted to the main dispatch queue (`dispatch_get_main_queue()`)? Keep in mind that the code path may be indirect.

If so, then that's probably the problem.

The main dispatch queue is serial. It will only run one task at a time. Running the open panel modally from such a task means that no other tasks will be started until the open panel and the rest of the current task completes. Apple, in their infinite wisdom, have made it so that some aspects of presenting files in the open panel rely on tasks submitted to the main dispatch queue. In your case, those tasks never run until after the panel has been closed and their results are no longer needed.

When this happened to me, it seemed like there was some timeout on the wait for those results. After a minute or so, the files showed up, but with generic icons.

To avoid this problem, you will need to use `-[NSObject performSelectorOnMainThread:...]` or `CFRunLoopPerformBlock()`. Both of those are based on the main run loop, which is not serial. It is re-entrant. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23856486/1312143) for more specifics on that.

Comment: Thanks. I added some background info to the post. No use of `dispatch_get_main_queue()` is involved. The secondary thread is created with `detachDrawingThread:toTarget:withObject:` and from there, it calls out to the panel (via a delegate object that manages it) with `performSelectorOnMainThread:`.

Comment: I now tested the code on a second thread without starting the simulation  and it worked fine. So it looks like this issue has little to do with my Cocoa code, but rather with the simulation on the second thread that might be interfering with I/O in a way that makes the panel miss out on something.

Comment: You could try sampling the process when it's failing to fill in files in the panel. Use the `sample` command-line tool or Activity Monitor. Post the sample report in your question.